# Do the screeds against Jerusalem in the prophets only apply to their original context or do they do double duty as prophecy about 70 CE?

Tags: nevua-prophecy, navi-prophets, prophecies

Do Jewish scholars consider it appropriate to understand the Shoah of c. 70-74 CE through the prophetic screeds regarding the destruction of Jerusalem and the first Temple?

Answer (score 3):

When someone talks about a historical period called "the Shoah", by the way, they mean the Holocaust, 1939--1945. The period you're describing is just called "the destruction of the Second Temple."

Anyhow --  you're asking if we read some of Lamentations (and the curses near the end of Deuteronomy) as prophetically referring to the Second Temple's destruction? Solid yes. Whether the Midrash is saying that's literally what was intended, or that those verses could also be applied to that situation homiletically, is a different question.

Have a look at the [Midrash on the book of Lamentations](https://www.sefaria.org/Eikhah_Rabbah%2C_Petichta.1?lang=en), and you'll see references to the Roman destruction.

Same goes for the couple of pages of Talmud [starting with Gittin 56](https://www.sefaria.org/Gittin.56a.11?lang=en) focused on the Second Temple destruction; it's full of references to verses written long earlier.